# 2D irregular aggregation of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, binning

I'm trying to bin a symmetric matrix with irregular intervals in R but am not sure how to proceed. My ideas are:

- Reshape the matrix to long format, aggregate and cast it back?
- Bin as-is in both dimensions (somehow... tapply, aggregate?)
- Keep the regular binning but for each of my (larger) irregular bins, replace all inner values with their sum?

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
set.seed(42)

# symmetric matrix
a <- matrix(rpois(1e4, 2), 100)
a[upper.tri(a)] <- t(a)[upper.tri(a)]

image(x=1:100, y=1:100, a, asp=1, frame=F, axes=F)

# vector of irregular breaks for binning
breaks <- c(12, 14, 25, 60, 71, 89)

# white line show the desired bins
abline(h=breaks-.5, lwd=2, col="white")
abline(v=breaks-.5, lwd=2, col="white")
```

[image: symmMat]

(The aim being that each rectangle drawn above be filled according to the sum of values within it.) I'd appreciate any pointers of how best to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24842040/1274516) provides a great starting point using `tapply`:

```
b <- melt(a)

bb <- with(b, tapply(value, 
    list(
      y=cut(Var1, breaks=c(0, breaks, Inf), include.lowest=T), 
      x=cut(Var2, breaks=c(0, breaks, Inf), include.lowest=T)
    ),
    sum)
)

bb
#          x
# y          [0,12] (12,14] (14,25] (25,60] (60,71] (71,89] (89,Inf]
#  [0,12]      297      48     260     825     242     416      246
#  (12,14]      48       3      43     141      46      59       33
#  (14,25]     260      43     261     794     250     369      240
#  (25,60]     825     141     794    2545     730    1303      778
#  (60,71]     242      46     250     730     193     394      225
#  (71,89]     416      59     369    1303     394     597      369
#  (89,Inf]    246      33     240     778     225     369      230
```

These can then be plotted as rectangular bins using a base plot and `rect` — i.e.:

```
library("reshape2")
library("magrittr")

bsq <- melt(bb)

# convert range notation to numerics
getNum <- . %>%
  # rm brackets
  gsub("\\[|\\(|\\]|\\)", "", .) %>%
  # split digits and convert
  strsplit(",") %>%
  unlist %>% as.numeric

y <- t(sapply(bsq[,1], getNum))
x <- t(sapply(bsq[,2], getNum))

# normalise bin intensity by area
bsq$size <- (y[,2] - y[,1]) * (x[,2] - x[,1])
bsq$norm <- bsq$value / bsq$size

# draw rectangles on top of empty plot
plot(1:100, 1:100, type="n", frame=F, axes=F)
rect(ybottom=y[,1], ytop=y[,2],
     xleft=x[,1], xright=x[,2], 
     col=rgb(colorRamp(c("white", "steelblue4"))(bsq$norm / max(bsq$norm)), 
             alpha=255*(bsq$norm / max(bsq$norm)), max=255),
     border="white")
```

[image]